# Ipe - vektor drawing - i cannot write æ,ø,å, - danish symbols - need help with preamble

Tags: pdftex, unicode, draw, ipe, scandinavian-letters

in Ipe (The Ipe extensible drawing editor) i am not able to write å or (æø). i am aware there is a preamble settup in EDIT-> Document properties.

the problem is i set the preamble up to danish, as normal. and i testet if it works in miktex (it works) but it will not work in Ipe. the letter `å` is displayed as blank.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %thanks's daleif
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
```

if i do not setup the preamble it cannot display any latex generatet symbols. (so a subscript ends up as normal latex code. `P_0` but what i need to write i dont understand.

and yep you bet i did - tried leaving out

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
```

but did not work.

this problem is in both math and normal but i write in picture as mathmod.
[image: picture of symbols when i changed preamble]

can someone try to use my code and try to display `æ,ø,å`
can someone solve the problem - tell me what i need to write in the preamble

thanks

Comment: Can you configure your toolchains to use Unicode? That’s often the best way to wipe out a bunch of technical debt to the last century.

Comment: this is not an option in Ipe ! i wish it  has but thansks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Edit/Document Properties/Latex preamble", write:

```
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

In the math symbol [Shift+4] box write:

```
 \text{æ,ø,å}
```

[image]

Comment: hhm yes it work but only after some fiddling with the program. first I have a texlive edition on my pc. it still would not work with the build in online Latex editor, but I used offline Latexeditor, it uses my texlive edition. then it works but only as long as you do 2 things consistently. if you use math mode always use \text{æ,ø,å} (you don't need the commas) and only in the text mode is it allowed to NOT use the "/text{}" so in that mode you can write " hello æ ø å" and it works

Comment: so overall THX to Moshe Gueta, i am regular user and even if its from Christmas, your help has not been invain